# Git diff does not show colors in VS code devcontainer

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have some problem with git diff on ubuntu in vs code.
I have prepared some project and devcontainer for it.
The container was build based on python3.11-apline.

When I open the project in normal terminal - i can see all difs in red and green colors. As expected.

In vs code - im opening the project in devcontainer. the git diff or git diff --color - shows all diffs but not highlighted as red or green.

For test I have saved diffs to file and then opened in the same terminal.

```
git diff --color > foo.txt

cat foo.txt
```

And all colors appeared!

I have also tried different vscode themes. All the same.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution.

Installing less package resolves the problem:

`apk --update add less` in running container or just add the less to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk update \
    && apk \
    (...)
    less \
    (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `git config color.diff` in the DevContainer terminal. If it returns auto or always, colors should be enabled. If not, you can enable colors by running `git config --global color.diff auto`.

Comment: I have also tried it in the devcontainer.
Running "git config color.diff" returns auto.